# Should I define a FOREIGN KEY column as NULLable?

Tags: database-design, schema, foreign-key, erd

I've been developing some database structure to cover the following business rules:

- An **invoice** has many **invoice_items**.
- An **invoice** may have many **refunds**
- A **refund** has many **invoice_items**.
- All **items** should be from the same **invoice**.
- A **refund** should always have **items**.

So I came up with the entity-relationship diagram (ERD) shown bellow:

[image: ERD 1]

I'd like to see which **invoice_items** are included in the **refund**.

However, in this case, it would not be possible to add a FOREIGN KEY (FK) (`InvoiceItems => refunds`). The reason is that an **invoice** may or may not have **refunds**.

So I modified the diagram as follows:

[image: ERD 2]

Here I could add the FK (`refund_invoice_items` => `invoice_items`)

#### Questions

I think this can work around the FK problem, so: Do you think this is an appropriate approach or have any ideas about it?

The main question is that if I could store NULL marks in the FK column, the first example would be better? (In my case I always add NOT NULL constraint to columns defined as FKs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, your first diagram is good enough (in physical model perspective) with details like the following:

```
[invoice table]
invoice_id primary key
....

[refund table]
refund_id primary key,
invoice_id NOT NULL, -- FK
....

[invoice_item table]
invoice_item_id primary key,
invoice_id NOT null, -- FK
refund_id NULL  -- FK
....
```

The data generation flow is

1. An Invoice is created in  [invoice table]
2. One or more Invoice_items are created in [invoice_item table]
   referring to the invoice_id in step 1.(note invoice_id canNOT be NULL as defined in [invoice_item table], while refund_id can be null)
3. When a refund record is generated, an associated invoice_id will be
   inside the record, and one or more invoice_item records (belonging
   to that invoice_id) will consequently be updated for their
   refund_id column.

However, for a pure normalized data model, your second model is more robust (note, your current model diagram has a typo, the relationship between REFUNDS and REFUNDS_INVOICE_ITEMS should be 1:N **not** N:1). 
The major advantage of model 2 is that it can meet your integrity requirement of (while model 1 cannot meet):

> All (refund) **items** should be from the same **invoice**.

note: I added *(refund)*

But model 1 is better for real world performance (fewer joins), and I often would sacrifice space for performance. In this case, model 1 will have lots of invoice_items with refund_id NULL, while in model 2, you do not have such concerns.

So at the end of the day, you need to balance your concerns between performance/convenience and strict business requirements. In Model 2, your integrity is guaranteed by database itself and you need to guarantee your integrity at application level in model 1.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Relationships (in ER modeling) can be optional.  There is no better way to represent a non-existent relationship in a foreign key than by putting in a NULL.  When you do a join, exactly the right thing happens.  When you do  a count, exactly the right thing happens.

The only reason to make a foreign key not NULLable is to make the relationship mandatory.  This rule might come from the subject matter, as captured by an ER model.  It depends on the situation.

In the question you posed, you already had a case of an optional relationship.  Not all invoices have any refunds.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, every `refund` should to have a FK in invoice's table and/or in invoice_item's table, not in the opposite side.

```
[invoices table]
invoice_id
....

[invoice_items table]
item_id
invoice_id FK invoices(invoice_id)
....

[refunds table]
refund_id
invoice_id 
item_id
....
FK invoices(invoice_id)
FK invoice_items(invoice_id, item_id)
```

Of course, you can get it with a single FK in invoice_items table.

There is no NULL value, because every time you add a new refund, invoice_item must exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I agree. However in my case, I'd love to see which invoice_items  is included in the refunds.  Refunds may have all invoice_items or maybe some of them. So in my point of view, the second example makes sense in my post. What do you think about it?

Comment: In your second diagram, the relationship between refunds and invoices is redundant.  It's really a transitive relationship between refunds and invoice-items and between invoice-items and invoices, which is also presnted in your diagram.

Comment: Also, I don't see what added value is provided by refund-invoice-items.

Comment: Most of all, please note that mcNets table definitions agree with your second diagram.  So his case for putting the FKs where they are ought to agree with your assessment of your diagrams.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, as @WalterMitty, I think that double FK between refunds-invoices and refunds-invoices_items is redundant. And just to cover all the possibilities, have you considered to have one refund without invoice?